# How to find all the possible combinations of a range in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

This is more of a math question than Python, but if I have a range 0-100, how would I go about iterating through all the possible ranges in this? For example, the lower bound could be 0, and then the upper could be anything from 1-100 and so on.

Would something like this cover all possibilities?

```
lower = 0
upper = 100
for i in range(0,100):
    for z in range(lower,upper):
       print("Range is" + str(z) +":" + str(upper))
    
    lower = lower +1
    upper = upper -1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Checkout [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> ```
> itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
> ```
>
> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> The combination tuples are emitted in lexicographic ordering according to the >order of the input iterable. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the >combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So >if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each >combination.

```
import itertools
arr = list(itertools.combinations(range(1,100), 2))
```

2. Using For loops

[For loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

```
arr = []
for i in range(1,101):
    for j in range(1,101):
        arr.append((i,j))
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is essentially all combinations of 2 numbers from 0-100. So 100 choose 2 different combinations. Python has [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for this:

```
for lower, upper in itertools.combinations(range(100), 2):
    # do something with lower and upper
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement something of your own (don't want to use `itertools` as mentioned in other answers), here's something that will work:

```py
lower = 0
upper = 10

for range_size in range(1, upper-lower+1):
  for j in range(lower, upper):
    if j+range_size > upper:
      break
    print(f"Range: [{j}, {j+range_size}]")
```

The outer loop iterates all the possible `size` of ranges, which can be as small as `1` and as large as `upper - lower`. Note that the `+1` is to make sure upper limit is also included in `range`.

The inner loop then starts from the `lower` bound and `print` all the ranges of size `range_size`.

**Edit:** If you want to get a sorted output like `itertools.combinations`, you can store the values in an array and sort that array.